# Is gsl::owner usable for shared-ownership?

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines, guideline-support-library

For example, can it be used in Qt for the following?

```
gsl::owner<QWidget*> w{new QWidget{parent}}
```

In this example, the ownership is shared by the new-site and the `parent`, because the code who has `new`-ed the object can `delete` `w`, and `W`'s destructor will take itself out of `parent` children list. However, if `w` is not deleted at the new-site, then `parent` will delete it in its destructor.

1. Is this an example of shared ownership, and
2. can `gsl::owner` be used for it?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of `gsl::owner` to create a warning if you forget to delete? Well, do you want to delete explicitly or do you want the parent to take care of it? In my opinion deleting an object with a parent is more like removing an element from a collection with the parent being a collection of its children.

Comment: @Homer512 I have no idea. Don't be blended by my reps, I'm completely clueless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this an example of shared ownership

No, you have two places claiming unique ownership.

> can `gsl::owner` be used for it

If `w` can outlive the object pointed to by `parent`, then it might become invalid, leading to undefined behaviour.

If you want a pointer type that interfaces with Qt's parent-child ownership, use [`QPointer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpointer.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems that https://www.stroustrup.com/resource-model.pdf agrees with the use of `owner` to designate unique ownership.

Answer (score 1):

> In this example, the ownership is shared by the new-site and the `parent`, because the code who has `new`-ed the object can `delete` `w`, and `W`'s destructor will take itself out of `parent` children list. However, if `w` is not deleted at the new-site, then `parent` will delete it in its destructor.

This is wrong. The code that has created this object should not delete it unless it is absolutely sure that the parent is still alive, otherwise you will get double-free errors (because parent would have freed the object already).

The correct solution is to use `QPointer` as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Indeed, I should have been more clear about these relations. I omitted that there's no type check at all when the parent deletes the child, or when the new-site deletes the pointer, whether the pointer is still in use (parent) or whether the pointer was already deleted (when new-site deletes it). Thanks for the clarification! Followup-question: How can I teach static analyzers about QPointer? Or will they already understand it? `QWidget(QWidget *parent)` is from Qt, I can't patch it up to use QPointer, unfortunately :(

Comment: For example, If my code says `QPointer<QWidget> p(new QWidget(parent))` static analyzers could complain that I have a weak owner, but not a strong owner, because they don't see that the parent pointer passed to the QWidget constructor acts as a potential deleter

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Do you have any specific cases where you get a warning about ownership when you do `QPointer<QWidget> p(new QWidget(parent))`?